# Eloquent going through 2 many-to-many relations

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 5 entities that look like this :

```
character --> character_equipement <-- equipement  --> stats_equipement <-- stats
```

I want to take for a defined character all of his equipements and for each equipements I need stats.

Character Model :

```
    public function equipements(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(EquipementsModel::class, 'stuff_equipement', 'id_stuff','id_equipement');
}
```

Equipements Model :

```
    public function stats(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Stats::class, 'stats_equipement', 'id_equipement','id_equipement');
}
```

Controller :

```
        $stuff = Character::with('equipements')->where('lien_stuff',$id)->first();
```

This way, I retrieve all equipements for the defined character. I don't know how to tell my Character model that he must look through Equipements Model to retrieve stats now.

I thought first way that while calling my controller, it will go through equipements() then look for a relation into his own model...

Comment: How does `StuffModel` relate to equipment?  Is `StuffModel` basically just the character?

Comment: StuffModel is the equivalent for my entity 'character', EncyclopedieModel is the equivalent for my entity 'equipement'

I edited my post to be more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dot notation to chain relations.  It's actually fairly easy once you get the hang of it.  I kind of guessed what the name of the column was on the stat to add up but hopefully you get the idea.

```
$character = Character::with('equipements.stats')->where('lien_stuff',$id)->first();

$totalStats = 0;
foreach ($character->equipments as $equipment) {
    foreach ($equipment->stats as $stat) {
        $totalStats += $stat->value;
    }
}
```